# Can I join Database Table with Excel file by query in python?

Tags: python, sql, excel, oracle, join

I have a Oracle Database table, excel file.
I want to join when query run.

like this.

```
xlsx_dat_pd = pd.read_excel("/file.xlsx")

sql_dat_pd = psql.read_sql("""SELECT UID 
                              FROM DATA.BASE_NM
                              WHERE UID IN xlsx_dat_pd.UID""", conn)
```

Can I join Datatable with pandas object in query?

Comment: Hi, Oracle has an option to create external table to get data from file. If you are interested in, I can write more details about it. Two main points to mention: 1) file should be located on database server 2) as remember, this solution doesn't support indexes, so if file is huge, performance wouldn't be hight.

Comment: I'd like to know the  library in python that provides the function **psql.read_sql** in your question?

Comment: Looking at your code, i reckon you are using pandas to extract both dataframes,
In that case you can use merge something like xlsx_dat_pd.merge(sql_dat_pd, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey'')

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
1. #Tomasz Because of company's security policies, it is not possible to stack data on a temporary table.
2. #YayatiSule pandas.io.sql as psql
3. #NishantPatel The amount of data is about 800 million, so I want to process it in the query.